# Remove weekend from array of the next 10 days

Tags: php, arrays, date, array-filter

I have created an array of the next 10 days, with a 2 days buffer (i.e. if it is a Monday, the array starts on Wednesday). I am now trying to remove weekends from my array but unsure how to go about doing this. Below is my PHP and the returned array:

```
    $date_buffer = strtotime('+2 days');
    $days = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $days[date($date_buffer)] = date("l, jS M", $date_buffer);
        $date_buffer = strtotime('+2 days', $date_buffer);
    }

    print_r($days);
```

This returns:

```
Array ( 
    [1548192409] => Tuesday, 22nd Jan 
    [1548365209] => Thursday, 24th Jan 
    [1548538009] => Saturday, 26th Jan 
    [1548710809] => Monday, 28th Jan 
    [1548883609] => Wednesday, 30th Jan 
    [1549056409] => Friday, 1st Feb 
    [1549229209] => Sunday, 3rd Feb 
    [1549402009] => Tuesday, 5th Feb 
    [1549574809] => Thursday, 7th Feb 
    [1549747609] => Saturday, 9th Feb 
)
```

Can somebody help me understand how I would filter out any Saturdays or Sundays from the above

Comment: It's unclear to me if you want every 2nd day after 2 days, or 10 consecutive days after 2 days from now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
$date_buffer = strtotime('+2 days');
$days = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    if (!in_array(date('w',$date_buffer), [0,6])) { 
        $days[date($date_buffer)] = date("l, jS M", $date_buffer);
    }
    $date_buffer = strtotime('+2 days', $date_buffer);
}

print_r($days);
```

Comment: This is close, but currently misses out weekend AND every other day (currently returns, Tuesday, Thursday, Monday, Wednesday, Friday, Tuesday, Thursday). Something to do with the date buffer which is just meant to offset the start date by 2 days

Answer (score 1):

This is a good job for the [`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) class. We set up a period of 10 recurrences of 2 days from the start time (in 2 days), and then can iterate through the dates, checking for a weekend day (day of week = 0 or 6) to exclude them from the output:

```
$start = new DateTime('+2 days');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, new DateInterval('P2D'), 9);
foreach ($period as $date) {
    $dow = (int)$date->format('w');
    if ($dow != 0 && $dow != 6) {
        $days[$date->format('U')] = $date->format('l, jS M');
    }
}
print_r($days);
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [1548194036] => Tuesday, 22nd Jan
    [1548366836] => Thursday, 24th Jan
    [1548712436] => Monday, 28th Jan
    [1548885236] => Wednesday, 30th Jan
    [1549058036] => Friday, 1st Feb
    [1549403636] => Tuesday, 5th Feb
    [1549576436] => Thursday, 7th Feb
)
```

If you wanted 10 **consecutive** days (excluding weekends) from 2 days from today, you would just change the second line of the code to:

```
$period = new DatePeriod($start, new DateInterval('P1D'), 9);
```

and the output would be:

```
Array (
    [1548197829] => Tuesday, 22nd Jan
    [1548284229] => Wednesday, 23rd Jan
    [1548370629] => Thursday, 24th Jan
    [1548457029] => Friday, 25th Jan
    [1548716229] => Monday, 28th Jan
    [1548802629] => Tuesday, 29th Jan
    [1548889029] => Wednesday, 30th Jan
    [1548975429] => Thursday, 31st Jan
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/LsWoI)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple answer using the while loop.

https://3v4l.org/0lpGX

```php
<?php

$x = 1; // Start
$y = 10; // Iterations Needed

$days = []; //Empty Array

while($x <= $y) {

    // Set Buffer
    $buffer = 2 + $x;
    // Get Date with Buffer 
    $date = date(strtotime("+$buffer days"));    

    // If the day is a weeday
    if(date('N', $date) < 6){
        // Add to array
        $days[$date] = date("l, jS M", $date);
    // If not, increase max iteration (example: 10 to 11)
    }else{
        $y++;
    }
    // Go to next loop      
    $x++;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($days);

?>
```

Which prints out

```php
Array
(
    [1548283397] => Wednesday, 23rd Jan
    [1548369797] => Thursday, 24th Jan
    [1548456197] => Friday, 25th Jan
    [1548715397] => Monday, 28th Jan
    [1548801797] => Tuesday, 29th Jan
    [1548888197] => Wednesday, 30th Jan
    [1548974597] => Thursday, 31st Jan
    [1549060997] => Friday, 1st Feb
    [1549320197] => Monday, 4th Feb
    [1549406597] => Tuesday, 5th Feb
)
```